# get radius of place with lat lng

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using places API autocomplete to let user search for a place and check if my database has values within that selected place. After the user selects a place, I get the following from the API as response.

```
    {address_components: Array(5), formatted_address: "Whitefield, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India", geometry: {…}, place_id: "ChIJg_wNXfMRrjsR-RUB2BKlzzA", types: Array(3)}
address_components: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
formatted_address: "Whitefield, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India"
geometry:
bounds: _.de
Ya: ce {i: 12.941353, j: 12.987782}
Ua: Yd {i: 77.7057753, j: 77.76729010000001}
__proto__: Object
location: _.L {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
location_type: "APPROXIMATE"
viewport: _.de {Ya: ce, Ua: Yd}
__proto__: Object
place_id: "ChIJg_wNXfMRrjsR-RUB2BKlzzA"
types: (3) ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
__proto__: Object
```

There's a `bounds` property. I am hoping to find the radius of the selected place using the bounds so that I can send places that are within that radius in my database.

The places API does not return Polygon coordinates as far as I know(I searched and could not find it).

The `geoWithin` allows only polygon coordinates(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#within-a-polygon).

If polygon coordinates are not available I thought of using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/ with `maxDistance` from the bounds radius.

How do I get the radius from the response returned from the API

Comment: also I don't know what the `_.de`, `Ya`,  `Ua`, 'Yd` is. Can someone please say what that is

Comment: The bounds appear to be minimum and maximum latitude and longitude, so it would seem the options are to either use those to create a polygon, i.e. `[[77.7057753,12.941353],[77.7057753, 12.987782],[77.76729010000001, 12.987782],[77.76729010000001, 12.941353]]`, or convert those to radians so that you can calculate the size of the enclosing rectangle and from that the radius.

Comment: The bounds shows describe a rectangle approximately 5.17km by 6.84km, so the radius of the largest circle that fits entirely within the rectangle would be 2.58km, and the radius of the smallest circle that encloses every point within the rectangle would be 4.29km.

Comment: @Joe how do I calculate that in general

Comment: Latitude and longitude are in degrees.  If you convert latitude to radians and multiply by the radius of the earth, you will get the approximate surface distance from the equator.  Likewise with longitude / distance from the prime meridian. I used 6378km for the radius of the earth.  If you happen to know the exact radius of the earth for the area of interest, you can be more accurate.

Comment: @Joe I see... thanks.